# Access to equally defined VM in different VLANs

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I have a working libvirt cluster and in order to perform some paralellization I have duplicated it. At the moment my scenario looks like this: two clusters whose VM definitions are exactly the same, i.e. same MAC, same IP but different identifiers. However, each cluster is set to a different VLAN.

Inside each cluster (VLAN) everything seems OK, from each VM I can ping the other VMs in the cluster, see the  neighbours, etc. Up to this point I access the different VMs through `virsh console`

However, when trying to *ssh* each individual VM I get the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.1 port 22: No route to host
```

My questions is: How could I *ssh* to the different VMs whose IP is the same but located in different VLANs?

Please bear in mind that the configuration should ideally remain as it is, i.e. two equally defined clusters that exclusively differ on the VLAN that each cluster belongs to.

Comment: Same network for multiple VLans ? This design seems weird...and bad...(but don't know `libvirt` through...)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. It may seem as a weird scenario but due to many reasons (heavy testing among them), currently this is the ideal case for us. To sum up, I am looking for a way to access the clusters based on their VLAN, if that is feasible at all.

Comment: `Inside each cluster (VLAN) everything seems OK` for sure, you are on layer 2 with no routing at all in this case. Are you VLans using the same gateway IP address ?

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your kind reply :) Yes, they are using the same gateway, please have a look below.
`bridge1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AA:BB:CC:00:FF:FF
          inet addr:192.168.0.250  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fe80:ecff:ecff:fe80/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:64512396 errors:0 dropped:1420545 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:218055 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:97019450920 (92524.9 Mb)  TX bytes:14637798 (13.9 Mb)`

Comment: I would like to add that the bridge is an Open vSwitch bridge